# Hibernate Insert Selected

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am trying to insert into a table the results which I just selected from this query, But I can't figure it out.

```sql
List<Object[]> results = em.createQuery("SELECT s.competition_id, s.data, s.discipline, s.category, s.player_id," 
    + " s.playerFirstName, s.playerLastName, SUM(s.points) as points FROM Score s"
    + " GROUP BY s.competition_id, s.player_id "
    + " ORDER BY s.points DESC", Object[].class).getResultList();
```

This select is working, but I need to insert this into the result table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Insert Select statement into regular SQL. You just need to provide the same amount of compatible columns into the query. I think it should be possible with group by records as well.

You may use Insert Selects with my Daobab (http://www.daobab.io)
An example:

https://github.com/daobab-projects/daobab-100plus-examples/blob/main/src/main/java/io/daobab/demo/example/c_talented/InsertSelect.java